# CODEHS While Loop Counter?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to figure this question regarding counting up While Loops and when they will exit: "Your friend is bored at lunch and is climbing the stairs for fun. He walks up two stairs, walks down one, walks up two stairs, walks down one, and so on. How many iterations of the while loop will it take her to walk up to the 10th stair?" (This is from CODEHS)

I've already tried out the code in my head and I keep getting stuck at 9. Apparently the answer is 10? This doesn't make any sense because on the 9th iteration of the while loop, you add 2 to 9 (stairsWalked), 9 + 2 = 11, you can't go through the if statement anymore and are stuck at 11 and thus, exit the while loop. So my answer was it stops at the 9th iteration of the while loop.

```
int stairsWalked = 0;
while (stairsWalked < 10)
{
    stairsWalked += 2;
    if (stairsWalked < 10)
    {
        stairsWalked -= 1;
    }
}
```

This was bugging me for a really long time so I decided to put the code in eclipse and I still got 9 as a result from counting the iterations from the while loop. (I named the class Jinji cause I was bored lol)

```
public class Jinji {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int stairsWalked = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (stairsWalked < 10)
        {
            stairsWalked += 2;
            if (stairsWalked < 10)
            {
                stairsWalked -= 1;

            }
            count++;
        }
        System.out.print(count);
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me understand conceptually why it's 10 it would be of a lot of help! Thanks <3

Comment: I thought there are **10** stairs: `while (stairsWalked <= 10) {`.

Answer (score 0):

```
0 -> 2 -> 1
1 -> 3 -> 2
2 -> 4 -> 3
3 -> 5 -> 4
4 -> 6 -> 5
5 -> 7 -> 6
6 -> 8 -> 7
7 -> 9 -> 8
8 -> 10 - exit
```

It is 9